# Shopify webhooks not wanted

Tags: php, api, shopify

I am connecting my website to Shopify using the API and Webhooks. When I create a product on my website, I want it to be created on Shopify. That works. But Shopify sends me back a Webhook telling me that a product has been created: So it creates the same product back on my website… I also want product to be created the other way.

I can’t use Shopify product id to check if the product already exists on my website because I haven’t received it yet.

I feel like I might find a way to make it work, but I am not sure it will be the cleanest way. I am wondering what is the best solution for this scenario.

EDIT: (Adding current ideas)

- The first idea that I have (I think it is a very bad way of doing it, but @Nathan told me to give talk about my ideas :) ), is to unsubscribe from product_create webhook and re-subscribe when I have the ID.
- The second one, is the make a request based on the product sku. That may work, but it doesn't seems like the strongest solution.

Any chance there is a way to just ask Shopify not to send me back the webhook when I create the product?

EDIT 2:
Other idea:

- Delay the execution of the webhook on my website with a sleep(5) so I have time to same the shopify ID before dealing with the webhook.

Comment: You should probably edit in your idea for a solution; even if it doesn't work, it will give answers a place to start and a better idea of what you (or other similarly-placed users later) need to know.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, I did the edit with 2 ideas that I have in mind right now. But none of those really please me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: when you create a product on shopify using the api, this return the product created. Whit this data you can validate the webhook, Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
You create the new product on your website:
Using the api also you [create it on your shopify store](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create)

```
//sample
POST /admin/products.json
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!<\/strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "images": [
      {
        "src": "http:\/\/example.com\/rails_logo.gif"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

shopify response at same time:

```
"product": {
    "id": 1071559589,
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!<\/strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "created_at": "2015-12-08T11:42:18-05:00",
    "handle": "burton-custom-freestlye-151",
    "updated_at": "2015-12-08T11:42:18-05:00",
    "published_at": "2015-12-08T11:42:18-05:00",
    "template_suffix": null,
    "published_scope": "global",
    "tags": "",
    "variants": [
      {
        "id": 1070325044,
        "product_id": 1071559589,
        "title": "Default Title",
        "price": "0.00",
        "sku": "",
        "position": 1,
        "grams": 0,
        "inventory_policy": "deny",
        "compare_at_price": null,
        "fulfillment_service": "manual",
        "inventory_management": null,
        "option1": "Default Title",
        "option2": null,
        "option3": null,
        "created_at": "2015-12-08T11:42:18-05:00",
        "updated_at": "2015-12-08T11:42:18-05:00",
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "taxable": true,
        "barcode": null,
        "inventory_quantity": 1,
        "old_inventory_quantity": 1,
        "image_id": null,
        "weight": 0.0,
        "weight_unit": "kg"
      }
    ],
    ...
    ..
    .
    .
```

Second:
Then you have the product data created, and you can save the id on a column of your product table website, to validate with the webhook from shopify.
simple!

Comment: If I understood well, that is what I was planning. But Shopify sends me the webhook before returning the response. So I can't compare it to any shopify id.

Comment: you can save webhooks in other table like `webhooks_table` with state column `false`, after the response search the `product_id` , if this exist then process and set the `state` to `true`.Thus every new webhook enter with  `false` state.

Comment: Ok my bad. It works as attended, problem was something else on my side. Thanks for opening my eyes :)

Comment: you're welcome. It seemed rare for me, because I built similar apps and always worked